# jQuery UI Dialog Buttons not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, x-cart

I'm attempting to use the jQuery UI Dialog box within a version of x-cart. The problem is that my buttons for the dialog do not show whatsoever. Here is my latest jsfiddle showcasing the functionality which i am trying to implement.

http://jsfiddle.net/iiminov/JSa3A/65/

When i actually go and implement this into my version of x-cart i get the following errors, and hence my buttons do not show: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

The line in which it occurs upon is this:
[image]

As i am not that good with debugging Javascript/jQuery i was hoping someone here could shed some light on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I see you're using a custom build of jQ UI - is it possible it's lacking some key module required for the jQ UI buttons? If you load jQ UI off of a CDN versus your local custom build, do you see the same behavior?

Comment: Yes in fact i have noticed that, and the dialog modal does work as it's supposed to, however the custom ui file is required for some key x-cart functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure what you can do then if you're locked into that version of the jQ UI library; it seems like your custom build is lacking one or more required modules. Are you able to append your own additional JS files? You could always do a build on the jQ UI site of only the Dialog & Button widgets (their dependencies will auto-select) and see if that resolves it. Again, may not be an option for PROD but it'd validate the source of the issue.